# split dataframe into 80% of 365 days from first charge into training and testing

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

I have a dataframe with columns: user, amount_spent, month, day, hour I am trying to split my dataframe into training and testing data; I want to get the first charge up until 365 days * 80% I am not sure how to do this. I created a yearly sales dataframe that contains a summary of the sales based on each user:

```
f1 = {'year': ['min', 'max'], 'amount_spent':['sum','mean', 'count','max']}
yearly_sales = df.groupby('user')['year', 'amount_spent'].agg(f1).reset_index()
yearly_sales.columns = ['user', 'sum', 'mean', 'count', 'high', 'before', 'after']
yearly_sales['duration'] = (yearly_sales.after - yearly_sales.before) + 1
```

I am new to this so if someone could help me create this column? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `Xcols` is a list of column names of predictors and `ycol` is the column name of target in your `data`.
You can use scikit-learn's train_test_split as follows.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data.loc[:,Xcols].as_matrix(), data.loc[:,ycol].as_matrix(),
    test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

For more information about the module check the documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html